# Using Yup to validate radiobox or checkbox value

Tags: reactjs, validation, react-hooks, formik, yup

I am using two library with is Formik and Yup. And trying to validate by the value stored on the radio box(check box as well) but seems like I cant find anything on google where I can get the actual value to check. I can use the name value to validate but is there a way to check validation by looking at the value? I will provide the example below.

```
  const initialValues = {
  A: "",
  B: "",
  C: [],
};

const onSubmit = (values) => {
  console.log(values);
};

const validationSchema = Yup.object({
  A: Yup.string().required("Required"),
  B: Yup.string().required("Required"),
  C: Yup.array().min(1, "Must be selected"),
});
```

and here is the return for react

```
return (
    <>
      <Formik
        enableReinitialize={true}
        initialValues={initialValues}
        validationSchema={validationSchema}
        onSubmit={onSubmit}
        render={(props) => <TreatmentView {...props} data={data} />}
      />
    </>
  );
```

And this is the rendered view below

[image]

I want to store that logic on the validationSchema. So again, I want to add a validation where checkbox with name "C" with value "4" can only be checked when radio button of name "B" with value "3" is selected. I did looked at the doc for the YUP and tried using the .value but seems like its not working..

Thank You!

Comment: Please, replace the image with something more readable.